# using purrr to extract elements from multiple lists starting with a common letter

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list of lists. One element in each list has a name beginning with "n_". How do I extract these elements and store them in a separate list? Can I use a combination of `map` and `starts_with`?

E.g.:

```
m1 <- list(n_age = c(19,40,39),
       names = c("a", "b", "c"))

m2 <- list(n_gender = c("m","f","f"),
       names = c("f", "t", "d"))

nice_list <- list(m1, m2)
```

I was hoping that something like the following to work (it doesn't!):

```
output <- map(nice_list, starts_with("n_"))
```

Comment: `lapply(nice_list, function(x) x[grepl("^n_", names(x))])` in base R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
map(nice_list, ~.x[grep("n_", names(.x))])
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$n_age
#[1] 19 40 39
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$n_gender
#[1] "m" "f" "f"
```

Or using `starts_with`

```
map(nice_list, ~.x[starts_with("n_", vars = names(.x))])
```

Or to flatten the nested `list`, you could do

```
unlist(map(nice_list, ~.x[grep("n_", names(.x))]), recursive = F)
#$n_age
#[1] 19 40 39
#    
#$n_gender
#[1] "m" "f" "f"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could (ab)use partial matching of `$`:

```
map(nice_list, `$`, "n_")
```

(I don't really recommend it).

(And I can't figure out why `` lapply(nice_list, `$`, "n_") `` doesn't work (gives a `list(NULL, NULL)`).

Comment: Can you explain why you don't recommend this solution? It works so well for my purposes at the moment, but I'd like to know if there are any risks that I don't understand

Comment: Partial matching is a feature intended for interactive use. As a general rule, I prefer to use interfaces the way the developers planned them, so as to avoid surprises and brittle code. The fact that I don't understand something (why lapply fails here) is also a red flag. `lapply` is stable but `purrr::map` might change and break this. Though if it does the job for you, as long as you are aware of it and careful...